# Why is year reputation more than total reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I just visited link from my profile

[image]

http://stackexchange.com/leagues/31/year/askubuntu/2012-01-01/40166#40166

it says,

[image]

How my year reputation can be more than total reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemed to [have lost](https://askubuntu.com/users/40166/virpara?tab=reputation) some reputation due to down votes, removal of accepted answers or possibly deletion of questions with up votes.

The reputation league systems are not constantly updated as your reputation in the main sites are. You just need to wait for the system to catch up.